# Interaction in logistic models with R. Using * operator or create an interaction variable?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, interaction, interpretation

I want to test the presence of an interaction term in a logistic regression with glm().

The formula is:

```
Gest.hypertension ~ ART.conc + Parity + Age + Smoke + Nulliparity + Syst.disease.type
```

With Age the only continuous variable and the others categorical.

The interaction term is ART.conc (2 leves) x Parity (3 levels), which are also the variables of interest. I found two ways of representing the interaction in glm();

- By explicitly defining ART.conc * Parity, which create both simple and interaction effect.
- By creating an artificial new variable with interaction(ART.conc, Parity) and adding the simple terms.

This are the results, omitting the other controls variables (OR and p value presented):

```
model1: Gest.hypertension ~ ART.conc * Parity + ...

ART.conc->yes                       3.35     0.073 .
Parity->2                           7.15     0.001 **
Parity->3                             38     <0.001 ***
ART.conc->yes:Parity->2            0.262     0.054 .
ART.conc->yes:Parity->3           0.0532     0.009 **
```

---

```
model2: Gest.hypertension ~ interaction(ART.conc, Parity) + ART.conc + Parity + ...

interaction(ART.conc, Parity)->yes.1  3.35    0.072590 .  
interaction(ART.conc, Parity)->no.2   7.15    0.001206 ** 
interaction(ART.conc, Parity)->yes.2  6.26    0.002698 ** 
interaction(ART.conc, Parity)->no.3   38.05    0.000202 ***
interaction(ART.conc, Parity)->yes.3  6.78    0.011071 *  
ART.concyes                              NA         NA    
Parity2                                  NA         NA    
Parity3                                  NA         NA
```

so the two models give more or less the same results one one of the two terms is zero and that's ok. I have troubles understanding what happened when the two terms are different from zero. For example in the second model that keeping parity == 2 and passing ART.conc from no to yes, we pass from an OR of 7.15 to 6.26. Instead, applying what I understood of logistic regressions and interactions, the coeff for the case (ART.conc, Parity)->yes.2 should be
$$OR_{parity.2}*OR_{art.yes:parity.2} = 1.87$$
very different from 6.26...

Therefore, I'd like to know what I'm missing and which of the model should I use.

Thanks!

UPDATE!!!

Thanks to @gavin simpson answer I thought I solved the problem, and ditched the interaction() trick. But then I noticed a pretty silly error by me.

We said that to interpretate the interaction you do
$$OR_{simple.eff}*OR_{interaction.eff}$$
Taking in example the case ART.yes/Parity.2. I said that to compute the effect of interaction of ART on Parity with the classical method you should do 
$$OR_{art.yes}*OR_{art.yes:parity.2} ≈ 3.35*0.262 ≈ 0.87$$
But if you perform
$$OR_{parity.2}*OR_{art.yes:parity.2} ≈ 7.15*0.262 ≈ 1.87$$
I was troubled by this disparity. I need a number that could describe the overall risk of the pathology in the above mentioned case, and instead i got two numbers that i didn't know how to describe.
Trying to solve this I noticed my error. To compute the overall effect, is not enough to multiply one simple effect for the interaction effect, but you should add the other simple effect too!
$$OR_{simple.eff.1}*OR_{simple.eff.2}*OR_{interaction.eff}$$
or
$$OR_{art.yes}*OR_{parity.2}*OR_{art.yes:parity.2} ≈ 3.35*7.15*0.262 ≈ 6.26$$

6.26 is the same OR for the `interaction(ART.conc, Parity)->yes.2` that is produced using the interaction trick.

Therefore, using interaction(), with `drop=T` option and not putting at all the simple effects by themselves (to avoid the NAs), you have that model 1 and model 2 give the same results, with model two including the already computed effect of the interaction.

Comment: Note that if you want to specify the interaction term separately, there's also the `:` operator in the formula interface. That is, `A + B + A:B` is the same as `A*B`. Is the issue here simply that you're changing which category is the baseline?

Comment: yep I know about the A + B + A:B = A*B, they both represent model 1. Do you think the problem is the baseline? could you elaborate?

Comment: I don't know what the problem is yet because I found your question unclear. When you fit dummies and interactions with dummies you have to leave one level out, because of multicollinearity with the intercept; this category is the baseline. The coefficient estimates (and hence the significance) are relative to that. If you change the baseline, you change the coefficients.

Comment: Gosh, I wish you'd paste the *actual* output from the model. You've really butchered this so trying to reconstruct the issue is difficult, to say the least!

Comment: eheh, I created a wrapper above regression functions to have cleaner outout. I can't understand why glm, lm, don't have method for summary() to show OR, rounded results, CIs, and cut unwanted stuff. Or maybe I just don't know them...

Answer (score 3):

Using some dummy data similar to what you must have used:

```
set.seed(10)
dat <- data.frame(ART.conc = factor(sample(c("yes","no"), 10, replace = TRUE),
                                    levels = c("yes","no")),
                  Parity   = factor(sample(1:3, 10, replace = TRUE)))
```

and for simplicity, form the interaction variable and store it in `dat`:

```
dat <- transform(dat, interact = interaction(ART.conc, Parity))
```

OK, now the `model.matrix` will show us the conversion to terms in the model the represent the factor variables. First, the *correct* way:

```
> model.matrix( ~ ART.conc * Parity, data = dat)
   (Intercept) ART.concno Parity2 Parity3 ART.concno:Parity2 ART.concno:Parity3
1            1          1       1       0                  1                  0
2            1          0       1       0                  0                  0
3            1          0       0       0                  0                  0
4            1          1       1       0                  1                  0
5            1          0       1       0                  0                  0
6            1          0       1       0                  0                  0
7            1          0       0       0                  0                  0
8            1          0       0       0                  0                  0
9            1          1       1       0                  1                  0
10           1          0       0       1                  0                  0
```

And now the way you did it:

```
> model.matrix( ~ interact + ART.conc + Parity, data = dat)
   (Intercept) interactno.1 interactyes.2 interactno.2 interactyes.3
1            1            0             0            1             0
2            1            0             1            0             0
3            1            0             0            0             0
4            1            0             0            1             0
5            1            0             1            0             0
6            1            0             1            0             0
7            1            0             0            0             0
8            1            0             0            0             0
9            1            0             0            1             0
10           1            0             0            0             1
   interactno.3 ART.concno Parity2 Parity3
1             0          1       1       0
2             0          0       1       0
3             0          0       0       0
4             0          1       1       0
5             0          0       1       0
6             0          0       1       0
7             0          0       0       0
8             0          0       0       0
9             0          1       1       0
10            0          0       0       1
```

The obvious thing is that these two are *not* the same because there are far more terms in the design matrix for the method using `interaction()` than for the *correct* way.

Now, we also note why in the model with the `interaction()` term you get `NA` values for some coefficients. Compare the `interactyes.3` column with the `Parity3` column in the design matrix from the `interaction()` model. Look familiar? So the `interaction()` has created information that relates to the main effects terms you added to the formula alongside the `interaction()` variable. At the very least, you don't need to specify the main effects terms alongside the `interaction()` variable in that version of the model. However, it'd still be wrong even if you fixed that.

Consider

```
> with(dat, levels(interact))
[1] "yes.1" "no.1"  "yes.2" "no.2"  "yes.3" "no.3" 
> with(dat, table(interact))
interact
yes.1  no.1 yes.2  no.2 yes.3  no.3 
    3     0     3     3     1     0
```

What `interaction()` has done (by default, I'll add) is retain all possible combinations of the levels of the two factors; that's 6 even though we only observed 4 of them in this dummy data set. This shows up in the model matrix as a vector of 0s for both `interactno.1` and `interactno.3` if you just include the `interaction()` term in the model:

```
> model.matrix( ~ interact, data = dat)
   (Intercept) interactno.1 interactyes.2 interactno.2 interactyes.3
1            1            0             0            1             0
2            1            0             1            0             0
3            1            0             0            0             0
4            1            0             0            1             0
5            1            0             1            0             0
6            1            0             1            0             0
7            1            0             0            0             0
8            1            0             0            0             0
9            1            0             0            1             0
10           1            0             0            0             1
   interactno.3
1             0
2             0
3             0
4             0
5             0
6             0
7             0
8             0
9             0
10            0
```

Hence we won't be able to identify both of two all 0 columns, so you'll still get an `NA`.

In summ, the two ways you mention are not the same model and you'll cause yourself a world of pain if you try to fit interactions using the `interaction()` function.

Hopefully by now you realize these forms aren't the same and why, and more importantly why it is a bad idea to circumvent R's formula interface notation.

#### Aside

I mentioned the default behaviour of `interaction()`. You can do better by adding the `drop = TRUE` to the call:

```
> with(dat, levels(interact2))
[1] "yes.1" "yes.2" "no.2"  "yes.3"\
```

Now we only have the four observed levels. Then you can do:

```
> model.matrix( ~ ART.conc + Parity + interact2, data = dat)
   (Intercept) ART.concno Parity2 Parity3 interact2yes.2 interact2no.2
1            1          1       1       0              0             1
2            1          0       1       0              1             0
3            1          0       0       0              0             0
4            1          1       1       0              0             1
5            1          0       1       0              1             0
6            1          0       1       0              1             0
7            1          0       0       0              0             0
8            1          0       0       0              0             0
9            1          1       1       0              0             1
10           1          0       0       1              0             0
   interact2yes.3
1               0
2               0
3               0
4               0
5               0
6               0
7               0
8               0
9               0
10              1
```

But then this still isn't right because you have one more term than needed, again because R can't do the right thing about removing one of the combinations of levels which gets absorbed into the `Intercept` term. Note the `Parity3` and `interact2yes.3` terms; they are coded the same way; the `Parity3` term works with the `Intercept` term to give you the information in `interact2yes.3`.

Comment: Well I guess you are right :) strange, the interaction trick wasn't my idea, I found it somewhere. So someone is applying a wery flawed method out there! 2 questions: 1. what if I use drop=T and don't include the original variables? 2. One of the benefits of using a dummy interaction var was to be able to use then glht() to easily perform post hoc tests on factorial variables using linfct = mcp(inteaction = "Tukey").

Comment: EVERYONE STOP!!!! I noticed something! a flaw in my answer and a point in favor or the interaction() method! Check my update!

Comment: (please don't shout) What Answer? What update?

Comment: sorry, it was on verge of the excitement :). Still writing the update...

Comment: *Please* don't drastically alter your original question; make the changes an addition to the question.

Comment: done! Thanks a lot for your answer, it was fundamental to spot my error!

Comment: @Bakaburg If you make `no` the reference level for `ART.conc` then you should be able to do this as `Intercept` + the two main effects + the interaction. R is doing for you what `interaction()` does, the problem seems more related to having estimates for the quantities of interest, which can be controlled by setting appropriate reference categories, no?